# Joomla 3.8: how to configure standard spacing properties?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I´m rookie in Joomla. I'd like to do a fine-adjustment in the presentation of a bunch of icons in a toolbar that I've created using logo/image components in the layout editor for a certain theme. These icons are being presented with a too wide spacement between one another, and it seems that the cause is the property flex in the css file nucleus.css (.size-5 element, according to inspections in Firefox).

I'd like to know how to resolve this spacement issue, perhaps changing paramenter's values in this css file, if there is no other way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You will probably need to add a custom stylesheet.  I can help with the actual CSS if you can provide a link to the site. 
 http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/tutorials/adding-a-custom-style-sheet

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey, thank you for responding. Actually my site is in an intranet not reacheable from outside. We did a "patch" dealing with percents for now, but we are going to deep in the custom style sheet issue. Any updates I will post here. By now I thank you again for your interest...